# Есть ли скрипт для скачивания с google play?

Tags: php, google-play

Как можно скачивать приложение с гугл плей через php скрипт? Это нужно что бы отдавать готовый файл пользователям.

Может быть, есть готовое решение? (сайты которые скачивают не нужны, нужны **скрипты**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не так просто. Максимум, что я видел - это [расширение для хрома](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/apk-downloader).

Сделать это с серверной стороны сложно, т.к. нужна авторизация. Почитайте [это](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1809458) обсуждение, может натолкнёт на какие-то мысли.

Периодически появляются скрипты вроде [такого](https://gist.github.com/arulrajnet/d50d0e81eaa354297347) и [такого](https://github.com/devctang/scripts/blob/master/google-play-market-apk-crawl/php/google-play-crawl.php). Можете доработать.